# SwiftUI: Perpetual Diagnostic Error When Building NavigationBar

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, and I'm trying to build this nav bar using Xcode 12.4:

[image]

Here is the entirety of my view:

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        //Background Color
        Color("DosDark")
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        Text("Hey.")
        //Nav bar styles
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Preferences")
                    .navBarTitleDark()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(
          leading: NavClose(), //<-- This is where the trouble starts
          trailing: NavAbout()
        ) 
      }
    }
  }
}

struct NavClose: View {
  var body: some View { //<-- Inexplicable error here
    Button(action: {
      print("Close...")
    }){
      Image("close-blue")
    }
  }
}

struct NavAbout: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      print("Show about stuff...")
    }) {
      Image("about-blue")
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the title to render okay, but as soon as I add the `.navigationBarItems` bit, I see an error endlessly on my `struct` that I'm trying to pull in:

[image]

When I try putting the `Button` directly in `.navigationBarItems` (without using an external `struct`) I still see the error on that line:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make Xcode give me a real error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, but `.navigationBarItems` was deprecated for the preference of `toolbar` and probably you have newer version where they are already conflicted.

The solution is to use only toolbar with corresponding placements, like

```
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                NavClose()
            }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavAbout()
            }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            VStack {
                Text("Preferences")
                .navBarTitleDark()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I didn't know about the deprecation of `.navigationBarItems` (and good riddance).  It looks like the root of the problem is the `Button()`. If I replace it with just a `Image("close-blue")` it works. There's something about the `Button` closure syntax that it doesn't like. 

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. I had a `typealias` named `Button` and Xcode was choking on it. D'oh! ‍♂️ Thanks again for your help!